# How to Implement an if/else based in SAPUI5 Controller?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to do an if/else based on the checkbox flag. Below are snippets of my view and controller. I am getting a syntax error on the last but one line. Anyone has any clue?

View-

```
<mvc1:View
   controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc1="sap.ui.core.mvc1">

<CheckBox id="i1" text="Test" selected="false" select ="checkDone" enabled="true" />

</mvc1:View>
```

Controller-

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App", {
        checkdone: function() {
            var check = this.byId("i1").getSelected();
            if (check = true) {
                alert("Successful");
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    })
};);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to remove `return ''` line.

Moreover, I would advice you to use `if (check === true)` or `if (check)` plus it seems to be more beneficial if you get selected checkbox by

```
checkDone: function (oEvent) {
     var bSelected = oEvent.getParameter('selected'));
}
```

If these hints don't help, check semicolons and brackets. In general every IDE should advice you something if it is wrong. I think that end of your controller should be like this:

```
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but emptying the else block will also lead to error and  the syntax error persist even after making the rest of changes you suggested.

Comment: Yes, it seems that something is wrong with braces and semicolons. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed some of the things in your code,

Get the event in **checkdone** method and try to get the selected data from that event instead of id.

While comparing with the true use **===** instead of **=**.

And in the last you are using the **semicolon** in the wrong places. So thats why you are getting the errors.

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App", {
        checkdone: function(oEvent){
            var check = oEvent.getParameter('selected');
            if (check === true){
                alert("Successful");
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you have used extra semicolon in last line

```
 sap.ui.define([ "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller" ], function(Controller) {
     "use strict";
     return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App", {
         checkdone: function() {
             var check = this.byId("i1").getSelected();
             if (check = true) {
                 alert("Successful");
             } else {
                 return '';
             }
         }
     })
 };);//extra semicolon
```

Updated code:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App", {
        checkdone: function() {
            var check = this.byId("i1").getSelected();
            if (check) {
                alert("Successful");
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    })
});//remove exta semicolon
```